# ACCESS 2003 and MySQL - problems with linked tables

Tags: mysql, microsoft-access-2003

I have an **MS-ACCESS 2003** application with linked tables located in **MySQL  5.7.25**.

The Forms and Queries work correctly with the linked tables, as long as the tables include up to **X** records, depend which table.

**When a table exceeded X records, there is one of 2 problems (depend which table):**

1. **A table with 4-5 fields (works well with about up to 200 records):**  When opening the table in ACCESS in View mode, I get the "ODBC -
   call failed" message, and all fields have "#Name?" value. **But**, when
   accessing the table data from the Forms, the data is displayed OK.
2. **A table, with 20 fields (works well only up to 100 records)**: In View mode in ACCESS, I can see all data correctly.  **But** I cannot
   access the data from my Forms. The table and fields are not
   recognized in the code.

When working with these table directly from Access (not as linked tables) - all works correctly, no matter how many records are in the tables.

Hope you can help me with these issues. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have to adjust some parameters in your connector.  I haven't used this setup for awhile, but I recall that there were a number of connection parameters that had to get set correctly, and didn't have much documentation.  The one that I had trouble with was something like auto reconnect.  Because without it the connection would time out and go away.  Then you would have to reconnect before you could get any data in or out again.  After getting it set correctly the link would be persistent.

Comment: The auto reconnent is set. I already tried all other parameters. Nothibg helps to solve the problem.